# Сделать модальный вид прозрачным

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Предыдущие виды получается сделать прозрачными, но когда переключаюсь в модальный - экран становится черным.

Comment: @Indeets, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для модального представления может презентоваться новое окно UIWindow или что-то еще, по идее прозрачным его сделать получиться не должно, только если попробовать выставить всем `superview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`,
но даже в этом случае не факт, что у вас получится. Можете попробовать, не презентуя положить нужное вью с анимацией, как будто презентуете модальный вью контроллер.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу оговорюсь, могу ошибаться, ибо сталкивался с этой проблемой давно и под рукой сейчас нет ни кода, ни даже мака, чтобы проверить. Насколько помню, это зависит от свойства `modalPresentationStyle UIViewController`'а, на котором вы показываете модальный вид, при одном из стилей (кажется, UIModalPresentationCustom) вы можете делать экран полупрозрачным, правда, работает это не на всех версиях операционки (кажется, не пахало на 4.3).

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то примерно так:

```
@interface MyPopowerViewController ()
{
    UIWindow *window;
}    
@end

@implementation MyPopowerViewController

- (void)presentPopower
{
    [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window makeKeyWindow];
    [window setHidden:NO];
    [window setAlpha:0];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                     animations:^{
                         [window setAlpha:1];
                     }];
}

- (void)dismissPopower
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                     animations:^{
                         [window setAlpha:0];
                     }];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configure
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.5 alpha:.5]];
    [window setRootViewController:self];
}
```

В этом случае окно будет появляться, как вам угодно, при этом в процессе не будет мелькать черноты, как если бы вы работали с фоном view внутри окна.
Фон у окна можно оставить пустым.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при смене ViewController-а даже в модальной транзакции, старый ViewController выгружается, и вместо него Вы видите черный экран. Можно воспользоваться UIContainerViewController - это функционал, который позволяет поверх одного ViewController-a показывать другой. Почитать о нем можно [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). Работает начиная с iOS5. Примерный код:

```
@implementation UIViewController (ShowModal)

- (void)showModal
{
    __weak UIViewController *mainViewController = [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow rootViewController];
    self.view.alpha = 0;

    [self willMoveToParentViewController:mainViewController];
    [mainViewController.view addSubview:self.view];
    [mainViewController addChildViewController:self];
    self.view.frame = mainViewController.view.bounds;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:mainViewController];

    __weak typeof(self)_self = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        _self.view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

- (void)hideModal
{
    __weak typeof(self)_self = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        _self.view.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [_self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_self removeFromParentViewController];
        _self.view.alpha = 1;
        [_self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }];
}

@end
```